# How to change the icon that will be displayed on taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, application-icon

In my WPF I set the application icon like below.
Project property -> Application tab -> Resources Icon and manifest
[image]

So I can see this icon on the wpf windows. but the icon of taskbar is default icon.
How can I set it with application icon.

Application icon

[image]

Taskbar icon

[image]

Comment: I guess you didn't set the icon on the mainwindow.  Or google before posting. https://www.technical-recipes.com/2016/setting-the-application-icon-in-wpf-xaml/

Comment: @Andy I have already read this article before posting my question, it did not mention about taskbar icon but only application icon.

Comment: What @Andy is saying is that in mainwindow's properties you can set an icon for the window. Try that. If that doesn't work, run the executable that is generated and see if it shows correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My project is the packaged application of WPF app.
In Images folder of Windows Application Packaging App, there are several default images.
[image]

I replaced them with my custom images.

[image]

So that I could resolve the task bar icon problem.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the icon via XAML:

```
<Window
    ...
    Icon="nvicon.ico">
</Window>
```

Also be sure to build in release mode to double check your success, as there are some cases where a debug build does not apply icons (for reasons i do not know).

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried with your suggestion but I could not get any luck.